# google functions: access to google storage bucket from a function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a google function in one project. If I wish to access a bucket (not set to public) for purposes of reading from another project (of another user), how should the same be set for google functions project?

I was trying to approach this by setting the IAM of the storage project to that of the functions project. However, I am not clear which user-account must be provided the access?

Thanks

Comment: Give the code in the other project a service account with the appropriate permissions (reader, editor).

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. The other project (viz. the one that has a function) would already be having an account. Is it not? Or do I need to create a separate service account?

Comment: The way it's supposed to work is that you create an account in the project to be accessed, then share it with the code that needs to access it, wherever it lives.

Comment: for example: it has a compute-engine service account, google cloud functions service agent account. Do one of these need to have access to the reader/ editor permissions in the google storage project?

Comment: Oh. understood. Let me give that a shot. Thanks

Comment: That worked @DougStevenson. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want GCF in project-a to read from GCS bucket "bucket-b" in project-b. Then give PROJECT-B@appspot.gserviceaccount.com the storage.objectViewer IAM permission in project-b (or to bucket-b specifically).

Comment: Thanks @David. The method suggested by Doug Stevenson (above) did work as I shared. Let me try your suggested method and update in this post.